# uisearchdisplaycontroller dimming view color

Tags: uisearchdisplaycontroller, uicolor

I am trying to get color of uisearchdisplaycontroller dimming view. I am trying like this. But it is not like that color. May I know what is the color? Does it depend on each ios version as well?

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.05f alpha:0.1f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)

Black color with 40% opacity